# Add a column of normalised values based on sections of a dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have got a dataframe of several hundred thousand rows. Which is of the following format:

```
   time_elapsed  cycle
0          0.00      1
1          0.50      1
2          1.00      1
3          1.30      1
4          1.50      1
5          0.00      2
6          0.75      2
7          1.50      2
8          3.00      2
```

I want to create a third column that will give me the percentage of each time instance that the row is of the cycle (until the next time_elapsed = 0). To give something like:

```
   time_elapsed  cycle  percentage
0          0.00      1           0
1          0.50      1          33
2          1.00      1          75
3          1.30      1          87
4          1.50      1         100
5          0.00      2           0
6          0.75      2          25
7          1.50      2          50
8          3.00      2         100
```

I'm not fussed about the number of decimal places, I've just excluded them for ease here.

I started going along this route, but I keep getting errors.

```
data['percentage'] = data['time_elapsed'].sub(data.groupby(['cycle'])['time_elapsed'].transform(lambda x: x*100/data['time_elapsed'].max()))
```

I think it's the lambda function causing errors, but I'm not sure what I should do to change it. Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) for division instead `sub` for subtract, then solution is simplify - get only `max` per groups, multiple by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html), if necessary [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html) and last convert to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
s = data.groupby(['cycle'])['time_elapsed'].transform('max')
data['percentage'] = data['time_elapsed'].div(s).mul(100).round().astype(int)
print (data)
   time_elapsed  cycle  percentage
0          0.00      1           0
1          0.50      1          33
2          1.00      1          67
3          1.30      1          87
4          1.50      1         100
5          0.00      2           0
6          0.75      2          25
7          1.50      2          50
8          3.00      2         100
```